# SQL Server 2008 table variable error: Must declare the scalar variable "@RESULT"

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm using table values for the first time as a parameter to a function in SQL Server 2008. The code below produces this error:

Must declare the scalar variable "@RESULT".

Why?! I'm declaring it on the first line of the function!

```
        ALTER FUNCTION f_Get_Total_Amount_Due(

      @CUSTOMER_LIST   [tpCSFM_CUSTOMER_SET_FOR_MONEY] READONLY

    )
    RETURNS [tpCSFM_CUSTOMER_SET_FOR_MONEY]
    AS
    BEGIN


 --Prepare the return value, start with initial customer list
 DECLARE @RESULT AS [tpCSFM_CUSTOMER_SET_FOR_MONEY]
 INSERT INTO @RESULT SELECT * FROM @CUSTOMER_LIST

 --Todo: populate with real values
 UPDATE @RESULT SET tpCSAM_MONEY_VALUE = 100

 --return total amounts as currency
 RETURN @RESULT

 END
```

Comment: What is `[tpCSFM_CUSTOMER_SET_FOR_MONEY]`?

Comment: A custom TYPE I had already created in the database

Comment: You do understand that custom types are often a bad idea? That they can cause huge maintenance problems?  I would avoid using them at all! From books online:
"To modify a user-defined type, you must drop the type by using a DROP TYPE statement and then re-create it."
This means you need to change all data using that type to another type first, then drop the type, then create the new one, then change all the fields you want to have that data type back to the new one. THis is amaintenance nightmare and no one I know who manages a large database will allow custome types to be used.

Comment: I did notice that I had to DROP first when changing. Thanks for the warning!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one compiles fine:

```
--Returns the name of the field to use to find results
ALTER FUNCTION f_Get_Total_Amount_Due(
    @CUSTOMER_LIST          [tpCSFM_CUSTOMER_SET_FOR_MONEY] READONLY
)
RETURNS @RESULT TABLE(
    tpCSFM_CUS_ID   uniqueidentifier PRIMARY KEY,
    tpCSFM_MONEY_VALUE  MONEY NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
--Prepare the return value, start with initial customer list
INSERT INTO @RESULT SELECT * FROM @CUSTOMER_LIST

--Todo: populate with real values
UPDATE @RESULT SET tpCSFM_MONEY_VALUE = 100

--return total amounts as currency
RETURN
END
```

Answer (score 3):

Your declaration would fall into the 'Multi-statement table valued function' case:

```
Multistatement Table-valued Functions
CREATE FUNCTION [ schema_name. ] function_name 
( [ { @parameter_name [ AS ] [ type_schema_name. ] parameter_data_type 
    [ = default ] [READONLY] } 
    [ ,...n ]
  ]
)
RETURNS @return_variable TABLE <table_type_definition>
    [ WITH <function_option> [ ,...n ] ]
    [ AS ]
    BEGIN 
                function_body 
        RETURN
    END
[ ; ]
```

Unfortunately the @return_variable cannot be declared as a table type, you'd have to copy the declaration of the TVP type into the function return table type.

Answer (score 0):

[I don't believe the table-valued functions got any new features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165.aspx) for the return value to be able to be a user-defined table type.

However, you can try: RETURNS @RESULT [tpCSFM_CUSTOMER_SET_FOR_MONEY] and remove your separate DECLARE.

I'll need to check it out when I get a chance to set up a test case.